# $([name*='test').toggleClass() Not working in safari

Tags: jquery, safari

I am trying to add/delete class using `toggleClass()`. It is working in Google Chrome, Maxthon and Mozilla Firefox but I can not make work in Safari.

```
$("tr[name*='" + $('#' + tr.id).attr('name') + "']").toggleClass("trHeatDCHover");
```

```html
<table  
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr name="test1"></tr>
    <tr name="test2"></tr>
  </tbody> 
</table>
```

What can the problem be? Is there any problem with `toggleClass()` in Safari? Is it maybe the `tr[name *= ]`?

Comment: Can you show us your HTML ?

Comment: Can you check, that this alone works `console.log($("tr[name*='" + $('#' + tr.id).attr('name') + "']"))`.

Comment: Are you sure that it's not working, or is the selector not matching what you expect? Maybe the CSS not specific enough to override existing styles?

Comment: What is in your `tr.id` object saved.? There is no `id` on the `tr` in the `HTML`.

Comment: In my tr.id is saved (for example) comp1048. I test if my code works at console.log and is working.

Comment: In Safari also?